# Facedetection using Android opencv-Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to detect face using Android opencv. But no face is detected in the image. For testing i have tried this code in pc and it is working. Why it is not working on Android? my opencv version is 2.4.9. Thank you.

```
private void my_opencv() throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, image);
        Log.d("MyTag","open_cv2");
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);



        File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        // Load the cascade classifier             
        CascadeClassifier  faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        /**/
        // Detect faces in the image.
        // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
        Log.d("MyTag","open_cv3");
        Rect rectCrop = null; 
        // Draw a bounding box around each face.
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
        {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new 

                    Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            // for crop face
            rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);   

            Core.putText(image, "Edited by me", new Point(rect.x,rect.y),
                    Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0 ,new  Scalar(0,255,255));
        }


        // Use the classifier to detect faces


     // Save the visualized detection.
        String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
               java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(), image.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(image, bmp);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + format+".jpg");

            Log.d("MyTag","$$$$$$$$$$"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM));
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();

        } catch (CvException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

solved code:

```
private void my_opencv() throws IOException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, image);
        Log.d("MyTag","open_cv2");
        //Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayscaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

        // load cascade file from application resources
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);

        File cascadeDir = getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir,
                "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
        {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();


        CascadeClassifier  faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
        //must add this line
        //faceDetector.load( mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath() );
        /**/
        // Detect faces in the image.
        // MatOfRect is a special container class for Rect.
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
        Log.d("MyTag","open_cv3");
        Rect rectCrop = null;

        Rect[] rect = faceDetections.toArray();
        // Draw a bounding box around each face.
//      for ( Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray() )
        for ( int i = 0; i < rect.length; i++ )
        {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect[i].x, rect[i].y), new Point(rect[i].x + rect[i].width, rect[i].y + rect[i].height), new 
                        Scalar(255, 0, 0));
            // for crop face
            //rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);   

            Core.putText(image, "Edited by me", new Point(rect[i].x,rect[i].y),
                    Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0 ,new  Scalar(0,255,255));
        }


        // Use the classifier to detect faces


     // Save the visualized detection.
        String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
               java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(), image.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(image, bmp);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + format+".jpg");

            Log.d("MyTag","$$$$$$$$$$"+ Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM));
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();

        } 
        catch (CvException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

[image: face detected in pc opencv]

[image: 2 face detected in android opencv]

Comment: did you check whether  CascadeClassifier  faceDetector  is loaded correctly or not from the location you are referring?otherwise the code looks correct.

Comment: I have added haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml and lbpcascade_frontalface.xml to the raw folder under res folder. Then, problem is solved. Thank you. However, there is small face detection problem.

Comment: instead 1 face it shows 2 faces. How to solve it?

Comment: have a try with detectMultiScale parameters.OR eliminate the smaller face box if you are looking for only one face in image.

Comment: How to eliminate the smaller face box? i am looking to detect just a single face in image.

Comment: Try to get rectangles of face which has both or at least one eye, by haarcascade_eye_left.xml and haarcascade_eye_right.xml of open cv and then get the largest face area and and you will get the final result as perfect face